# Heroku H18 "Server Request Interrupted" error sending image form data from Node to Flask, works from Postman

Tags: node.js, flask, heroku, axios

I am able to send image form data from Postman to my Heroku Flask server, but when I send from Node JS, I get the error described here: 
https://help.heroku.com/18NDWDW0/debugging-h18-server-request-interrupted-errors-in-nodejs-applications, ie "the socket connected, some data was sent as part of a response by the app, but then the socket was destroyed without completing the response."

```
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", image, {filename: image.url});
    return axios.post('herokuflaskserver.com/look-at-image', 
        data, {
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}` 
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        // 503 error logged here
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    });
```

I send that request to the Flask server which has a 200 according to that router.

```
@app.route('/look-at-image', methods = ['POST'])
def look_at_image():
    images = request.files.getlist("image")
```

But I get the error `sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted"`. I researched the error and tried adding a sleep of 10 seconds, and the error was gone but `request.files` was empty. I think the Flask server is sending a response before it gets all the image data. Does anyone know why it wouldn't work sending it from this backend? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by switching to using waitress instead of gunicorn

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT app:app
```

Comment: found this after some hours of debugging and searching and it worked, thank you soo much.